# How to create/set ArrayAdapter data on Spinner after Fragment is already created

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Trying to populate spinner with data that isn't retrieved until after the fragment is created. Test data works inside OnCreateView:

```
datesSpinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.calldatesspinner);
    /*
    String[] testData = { "Abc", "Def", "Ghi", "Jkl" };
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++)
        xVals.add(testData[i]);
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, testData);
    datesSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    */
```

But when I try to set the adapter on the spinner after the data is retrieved I get no error just a blank spinner? I commented out the test ArrayAdapter, created an ArrayAdapter for the data & gave it a new ArrayList then try to set it like I did in OnCreateView:

```
public void setSpinnerAdapter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < datesPulled.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Populating spinner: " + datesPulled.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("finished for loop");
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datesPulled);
    System.out.println("create array adapter");
    datesSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

The logcat is

```
04-03 14:18:02.412 9671-9671/? I/System.out: Populating spinner: 2017-05-01
04-03 14:18:02.412 9671-9671/? I/System.out: Populating spinner: 2017-06-01
04-03 14:18:02.412 9671-9671/? I/System.out: Populating spinner: 2017-07-01
04-03 14:18:02.412 9671-9671/? I/System.out: Populating spinner: 2017-08-01
04-03 14:18:02.413 9671-9671/? I/System.out: finished for loop
```

I thought there was a problem with the activity to fragment interface but the logcat tells me it's working fine. I tried to clear the test adapter with & reset it with the new ArrayList, leave the first adapter & create a second adapter, notifyDataSetChanged(), etc. but no luck. For some reason I can't create/set a new ArrayAdapter but I don't understand why?

Comment: call the setadapter() method in fragment's `onViewCreated()`

Comment: Are you setting the adapter in ui thread ?

Comment: Using onViewCreated got it as now I can see the ArrayAdapter created. Thanks for the reply @rafsanahmod007

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong layout for items, try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        testData
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note that spinner requires layout for expanded view and for collapsed view.